# How can I add markup (such as microdata or a <div>) to Zf2 breadcrumbs?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, breadcrumbs, microdata

I've constructed zf2 breadcrumbs for my application and it prints as expected:

```
<a href="main">main</a> > <a href="somthing-else">Something Else</a>
```

But what If I want to add some html tags?
Is Javascript the only solution or there is ZF2 way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define your custom partial for rendering by using `$breadcrumb` helper's `setPartial()` method.

1. Create a breadcrumb.phtml file `(application/partials/breadcrumb.phtml)`
2. In your partial;

   ```
   echo implode(', ', array_map(
       function ($item) { return '<span>'.$item->getLabel().'</span>' },
       $this->pages)
       );
   ```
3. Use the helper like this:

   ```
   echo $this->navigation()
             ->breadcrumbs()
             ->setPartial('application/partials/breadcrumb');
   ```

This functionality also [documented here](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.navigation.view.helper.breadcrumbs.html#rendering-using-a-partial-view-script).